# why it can't find when the relative path is correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pblg0.png)

i'm using create react app

src/reducers/index.js :
here is my reducer

```
const initialState = {
    menuOpen:false,
  };

  function reducer (state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'MENU_CLICKED':
      return {
       ...state,
        menuOpen: !state.menuOpen,
      };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

default export

src/store/index.js :
here is my store
i used relative path for import my reducer

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reducer from 'src/reducers';

//const middlewares = applyMiddleware(lister les Middlewares);

//const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
//const enhancers = composeEnhancers(middlewares);

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

Error :

```
ERROR in ./src/store/index.js 4:0-35

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/reducers' in 'C:\Users\apiot\Desktop\NoteToMyself\src\store'
```

Comment: Please add a `React` tag to the question. That way, it's more possible for those who specialize in React to help you rather than people like me, who were looking for pure-js questions. No hate at all, just helps both you and everybod else.

Comment: i just did it thx ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```js
import reducer from 'src/reducers';
```

It should be

```js
import reducer from '../reducers/index.js';
```